# Using a Shiny html application within a Qt application

Tags: qt, shiny

Just a general question: is it possible to display & interact with a Shiny-generated html page with charts, dropdown menus and other elements, within a Qt application? I've browsed at some documentation and videos for QtWebKit and WebView, and while mentions of basic html display are covered, I'm just wondering about more-involved uses.

The R code which I have on a VPS displays the Shiny app in html already, and is accessed via direct URL.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "interact": who does the interaction?

1. A human user interacts directly with the page - that's the easy case. Use the web view.

   Qt bundles a complete Chromium web engine. Anything Chrome can do, so can Qt's web view. As long as your page works in the Chrome version that uses the same Chromium version as Qt does, it will be fine in Qt's web view.
2. Your code interacts with the page - that's more involved. You'll have to add a remote control channel working on top of websockets to interact with the page. It could be as simple as the Qt application sending javascript to execute on the page, and receiving back the json-serialized results. That gives you the most power at the lowest implementation cost (a few dozen lines of javascript and C++).

Comment: By 'interact,' just a human user, doing no more than adjusting sliders or inputting a numerical value for the Shiny plots, etc to update, like seen in this example on Shiny's page [link]https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/kmeans-example.html